# How to mark things in the input?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

> #### Sipser theorem 4.4*
>
> $E_{DFA} = \{ \langle A \rangle \mid \text{A is a DFA and } L(A)=\emptyset\}$ is decidable.

I could not quite understand the solution, I'll quote it:

> On input $\langle A \rangle$ where $A$ is a DFA:
>
> 1. Mark the start state of A
> 2. Repeat until no new states get marked:
> 3. Mark any state that has a transition coming into it from any state that is already marked.
> 4. If no accept state is marked, accept; otherwise, reject.

My question is, what does it mean to even 'mark' something in the encoding? how do we do this? The encoding is merely a word from $\{A,c\}$, how would you 'mark' states?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a colloquialism.  It means, you keep a set of states that have been marked.  Initially the set is empty.  When you mark a state, you add it to that set.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your inputs are encoded in some alphabet $\Sigma$. You can then extend the tape alphabet to $\Sigma \cup \hat\Sigma$ (and probably some control symbols) where $\hat\Sigma = \{ \hat a \mid a \in \Sigma\}$.

Now, when you want to mark a part of the input, you just exchange the symbol(s) by its (their) marked version(s).

Comment: Here we're not talking about the input at all, only the states...

Comment: @TheNotMe In the solution you quote, an encoding $\langle A \rangle$ of DFA $A$ *is* the input to the algorithm. In other words, $\langle A \rangle$ is a string, certain parts of which may correspond to the states of $A$.